What are the specific terms in the "2024 Palestinian reconciliation agreement (also called the Beijing declaration)"?
It is claimed that the 2024 Palestinian reconciliation agreement (also called the Beijing declaration) is an agreement signed by 14 different Palestinian factions
Usually, a publicly signed agreement should be publicly accessible. Moreover, a "declaration" is naturally something declared to the public.
However, I failed to find any specific terms, conditions, or any contents related to that declaration. I failed to find any details about the declaration. I cannot even find the name of the "14 factions" and the names of the faction leaders who signed their names.
Question: what are the specific terms in this declaration?

An agreement doesn't have to be [entirely] public.

Moreover, it does not have to be an agreement, as they signed many more before.

"Usually, a publicly signed agreement should be publicly accessible" is that true? Obviously some agreements will be more sensitive than others, but I don't see any requirement to publish everything.

@timetakesitstoll A declaration should be public

@dodo: The full text was actually publicly available in Arabic on the day you wrote this Q. Just hard to find [for non-speakers of Arabic]--like the both us, apparently.

Update: Wikipedia now links to what appears to be the full text in Arabic of the "Beijing Declaration" -- skip to where it says (in bold) "اعلان بكين لإنهاء الانقسام وتعزيز الوحدة الوطنية الفلسطينية" to get past the journalist's intro to it. (That full-text page was published on July 22, but since I don't read Arabic, I couldn't find it then. English Wikipedia added that link a day after my answer below...)

Original answer below:
I'm not sure if they released the full text or not, but perhaps it doesn't matter too much. The gist of it appears to be that Hamas and Fatah have agreed to join in a future government, but the details of how that's supposed to happen don't appear to have been ironed out:

The two groups issued a joint statement announcing the deal but gave no details on how or when the government would be formed, saying only that it would be done “by agreement among the factions.” Both sides said the accord, which provided no guarantees, was only an initial step, and they promised to follow up on previous reconciliation agreements signed in 2011 and 2022.

A similar assessment by AP that the agreement:

offers only the broadest outline as to how the two factions would work together and provides no timeframe for its implementation.

FWTW,

Palestinian political experts generally dismissed the agreement as a rehash of several previous statements of reconciliation, including a 2022 accord signed by 14 Palestinian factions in Algeria. To date, none of those efforts has produced any lasting changes in the Hamas-Fatah rift.

I'm not sure one can find the text of the accord signed in Algeria either, in English at least. But at least it has a Wikipedia page, which does link to what appears to be the full text in Arabic.
And Western donor countries have objected to including Hamas in any Palestinian government, so there's that. Unless China wants to pick up the tab...
Also, given that you've tagged with this with the war, Israel has promised to destroy Hamas. And they've targeted their members in many circumstances, e.g. at border checkpoints with Egypt. So, at least in the current war context, any joint government including Hamas members might be presumably deemed a legitimate military target by Israel.

Al-Monitor quotes some snippets supposedly directly from the 2024 agreement, so perhaps at least snippets have been released to the press. (They also quote China's FM summary of it, aside from that.)

According to the Beijing Declaration, the factions agreed to achieve “a comprehensive Palestinian national unity that includes all Palestinian factions under the PLO framework, and to commit to the establishment of an independent Palestinian state with Jerusalem as its capital … with the help of Egypt, Algeria, China and Russia.” [...]
“A Palestinian national unity government will be temporarily formed with the consensus of all Palestinian factions and by a decision from the president,” the declaration continued. Said government will exercise its powers over all Palestinian territories, including the Gaza Strip and the West Bank, unify all Palestinian institutions and begin the reconstruction process, as well as prepare for holding general elections.
[...]
Speaking at the ceremony on Tuesday, China’s Foreign Minister Wang Yi said the most important outcome of the talks is that attendees agreed “to achieve the reconciliation and unity among the 14 factions” and to affirm that the PLO is “the sole legitimate representative of all Palestinian people.”
“The biggest highlight is the agreement on establishing an interim government of national reconciliation focusing on the post-conflict reconstruction of the Gaza Strip, and the strongest call is for truly establishing an independent State of Palestine in accordance with relevant UN resolutions,” he added.


FWTW, the US State Dept said in a presser yesterday that "we haven’t reviewed the full text", which perhaps means it's not yet easily available. https://www.state.gov/briefings/department-press-briefing-july-23-2024/ The ISW wrote on the same day "Hamas, Fatah, and China have not disclosed the full text of the declaration at the time of this writing." https://www.understandingwar.org/backgrounder/iran-update-july-23-2024 Yet WaPo writes today as if they read it, so who knows...

There's now a Wikipedia page for the 2024 declaration: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2024_Beijing_Declaration I don't see a link to the full text in that thogh. The most detailed piece I see linked there is the Al-Monitor one, which I've already quoted from.

Interestingly the user who contributed that (full text) link doesn't speak Arabic [according to their profile] but does speak Chinese, so I'm guessing the link to the Arabic full text was circulated in Chinese-language media at the time.
